# Is it possible to launch IE's proxy settings dialog from the command line?

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line

Is there a way to launch the IE proxy settings dialog from the Windows command line to save time going through menus in any application?

Comment: also that command would move to connections tab "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,4"

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Okay, I made a 15 minutes research for you and got following commands and a link.

To Open Internet Settings

```
inetcpl.cpl
```

To Open Internet Settings with Connections Tab

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,4
```

For more information
http://discussions.virtualdr.com/archive/index.php/t-41613.html

Comment: Slightly more concise...
`rundll32.exe inetcpl.cpl,LaunchConnectionDialog`

Answer (score 45):

I've found another one, shorter:

```
inetcpl.cpl ,4
```

You can use it in Run box or Command Prompt.

Comment: Any way to open LanSetting in launch window.

Comment: @shiv.mymail - Not without using some form of UI automation to click the button (AutoHotKey or native .NET classes). There is no method that exposes this functionality.

Comment: Thanks this is the only that worked for me. Running it through a run command.

Comment: The difference between this answer and the accepted answer is that command line from accepted answer will pause execution and wait for user to close the dialog. This one allows command file to proceed and run next command while dialog is open.

Answer (score 5):

The closest I can get is

```
control inetcpl.cpl,,4
```

which opens the *Internet Properties* dialog with the *Connections* tab preselected. Unfortunately it still requires you to click on *LAN settings* to get to the proxy settings.

Comment: Is there not a way to open the LAN settings dialog? (please)

Comment: it works but is there any options to open "LAN settings" dialog box? @Timwi

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively if all you want to do is select "Automatically detect Settings" You could just use Reg.exe to modify the Registry Directly.

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer  /d "hhttp=proxy-url:port;https=proxy-url:port;ftp=proxy-url:port;socks=proxy-url:port;" /t REG_SZ /f
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot to point me in the right direction. I ended up using the AutoConfigURL parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Not something new but still useful.

```
inetcpl.cpl ,4
```

And then simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on keyboard to change the proxy settings.

Comment: How this is differ from Vinicius Xavier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629054/4685428)?

Answer (score 0):

command: **`rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,4`**

you can found it on Windows ten forums [List of Commands to Open Control Panel Items in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/86339-list-commands-open-control-panel-items-windows-10-a.html)

You also can create a shortcut by steps below:

1) Right click or press and hold on your desktop, click/tap on New, and click/tap on **Shortcut**.

2) Copy the **command** you want from the table below as the "location", and click/tap on Next.

3) Type a name you want for this shortcut, and click/tap on Finish.

4) If you like, you can **Pin to Start**, **Pin to taskbar**, **add to All apps**, **add to Quick Launch**, **assign a keyboard shortcut** to, or move this shortcut to where you like for easy use.