# Use a batch file to open Internet Options, open connections tab, press ok

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is for a Windows 7 computer

I running a batch file (`.bat`) and want to configure it to open Internet Options and press the "Connections" tab and then press "OK".

So far I've got the following, which opens Internet Options:

```
inetcpl.cpl
```

I've been trying to follow the most upvoted answer [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071885/how-to-click-a-button-using-a-batch-file) to do it, using the following, but it doesn't work or even open Internet Options:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run inetcpl.cpl
```

Comment: What is the purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save this as `.bat` :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off

    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" 

exit /b %errorlevel%
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("control inetcpl.cpl");
WshShell.AppActivate("Internet Properties");

WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("+{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);

WScript.Echo("RIGHT keys.....");
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
//WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}");

WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the greatest answer of **@npocmaka**
and answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648366/is-it-possible-to-launch-ies-proxy-settings-dialog-from-the-command-line)
It has some improvements.

You can just save the following script as a bat file and run it.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" 
exit /b %errorlevel%
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,4");
WshShell.AppActivate("Internet Properties");

WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}"); 
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

I'd add as a comment to the **@npocmaka** answer, but I don't have enough reputation t oadd any comments here.
I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It's a string and has to be in quotes.

What I don't understand is why you pointlessly posted code without the error.

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\Users\User\Desktop\a.vbs
Line:   2
Char:   1
Error:  Object required: 'inetcpl'
Code:   800A01A8
Source:     Microsoft VBScript runtime error

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: @maudulus - definitely it has.Need to be - `WshShell.Run("control inetcpl.cpl")`